# Berry-Esseen bound for binomial distribution

Tags: probability-theory, reference-request, normal-distribution, estimation, binomial-distribution

From the [Berry-Essen theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Berry%E2%80%93Esseen_theorem) I can deduce

$$\sup_{x\in\mathbb R}\left|P\left(\frac{B(p,n)-np}{\sqrt{npq}} \le x\right) - \Phi(x)\right| \le \frac{C(p^2+q^2)}{\sqrt{npq}}$$

with $C \le 0.4748$.

**My Question:** Is there a better estimate for the constant $C$ than the one given above for the special case of the binomial distribution?

**Reason for my question:** The given inequality for $C$ holds for any standardized sum of any i.i.d random variables. But I am only interested in the case of binomial distributed random variables. From the answer to my question [Estimates for the normal approximation of the binomial distribution](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1290246/estimates-for-the-normal-approximation-of-the-binomial-distribution) I know, that I cannot except a better estimation. But I guess, that there is a better estimate of $C$ if one restricts the Berry-Esseen theorem to binomial distributions only. It would be great when you can point me to an article or a textbook with a better estimate of $C$.

**Note:** I am aware, that there are better approximations for the binomial distribution than the normal one. See [this answer](https://stats.stackexchange.com/a/157243/64742).

I already asked this question on [stats.stackexchange.com](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/157225/berry-esseen-bound-for-binomial-distribution), but I didn't get an answer there. I hope it is okay to reask the question here.

Comment: why is the above C(p^2+q^2)/sqrt(npq)?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The paper "[On The Bound of Proximity of the Binomial Distribution to the Normal One](http://www.researchgate.net/publication/215705591_On_the_Bound_of_Proximity_of_the_Binomial_Distribution_to_the_Normal_One)" - Nagaev, Chebotarev (2010) has improvements to $C$ specifically for the Binomial Distribution.

Theorem 2 on page 3 gathers together the results in the paper to show that $C$ can be taken to be .4215 in general.  The paper notes that an Esseen (1956) paper demonstrates that the bound has to be at least
$$\frac{\sqrt{10} + 3}{6\sqrt{2\pi}} \approx .409732$$
so they have found a relatively close bound.

However, there are some better bounds stated in the paper for specific situations.  When $n \leq 2000$ and $.02 \leq p \leq .5$ the bound can be taken to be $.4096$.  When $0 < p < .02$ it can be taken to be $.369$.