# Enhanced Berry-Esseen theorem for the digits of $\sqrt{2}$

Tags: number-theory, probability-theory, probability-distributions, irrational-numbers, probability-limit-theorems

The [Berry-Esseen theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Berry%E2%80%93Esseen_theorem) provides a second-order approximation to the central limit theorem (itself a first order approximation.) Higher order approximations are available, see [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Edgeworth_series). If the random variables are Bernouilli($p$), better approximations are available, this is a topic of active research. Before stating my question, Let me mention a recent result, which is the topic of a PhD thesis (the full thesis available [here](https://ubt.opus.hbz-nrw.de/opus45-ubtr/frontdoor/deliver/index/docId/732/file/Dissertation_Schulz.pdf)):

[image]

It seems that my question (below) is just a particular case of this result, not sure. Probably it is, but maybe I got it wrong.

**Question**

The proportion $q_n$ of binary digits of $\sqrt{2}$ (or any other normal number for that matter, say $\pi$ or $\ln 2$), among the first $n$ digits, satisfies

$$\sqrt{n}\cdot\Big|q_n-\frac{1}{2}\Big|<\frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}}\approx 0.398942 \mbox{ as } n\rightarrow\infty.$$

This assumes $p=\frac{1}{2}$. Below is the chart showing $\sqrt{n}\cdot|q_n-\frac{1}{2}|$ up to $n = 1,000,000$.

[image]

I don't expect an answer for $\sqrt{2}$ nor for any other normal number. All I want to known is, if the digits were i.i.d Bernouilli($\frac{1}{2}$), would this be correct? See related questions on Math.StackExchange, [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3326227/limit-associated-with-a-recursion) and [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1332799/berry-esseen-bound-for-binomial-distribution).

The goal is to try to prove a much weaker result for $\sqrt{2}$ hoping it would be easier than proving the result stated in my question, maybe something like $\log \log n \cdot |q_n - \frac{1}{2}| = o(1)$. That would be enough to prove that the binary digits of $\sqrt{2}$ are zero 50% of the time.

Comment: Possibly mathoverflow is better for you

Comment: Thanks, I am thinking posting on crossvalidated too. While my interest is purely number theory, this question is about probability theory and could prove useful in many other, non-mathematical contexts.

Comment: @VincentGranville It might be worth mentioning that we do not know whether $\pi$ , $e$ or any irrational algebraic number is normal in base $2$. Perhaps, more is known about the frquency of binary digits in $\sqrt{2}$.

Comment: @Peter: Exactly, and people should NOT try to prove this fact for these numbers (I once offered a $500k award for this!), but instead for random sequences.

Comment: I am a bit astonished how sure you seem to be that it is impossible, not that I see a chance for a proof, but I have not reached this level of sureness.

Comment: @VincentGranville So do you also regret that the mathematicians have widely accepted that $\pi$ is normal ?

Comment: @Peter: I have spent years on this problem, even written a book about it, and so far has made only little progress, but I am still hopeful to solve it one day, probably with the help of other mathematicians. I don't want to discourage other people to try, but many don't know what kind of nightmare it is, and anyone posting a simple proof for $\sqrt{2}$ would be laughed at here on this board.

Comment: @Peter, yes I regret that the mathematicians have widely accepted that $\pi$ is normal -- that includes myself. But the more I dig into this, the more I believe a solution might involve serious knowledge in combinatorics, topology, chaos theory, stochastic processes, functional analysis, dynamical systems and more.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/97933/discussion-between-peter-and-vincent-granville).